# How to use QAxObject to create Excel file in a Qt Application

Tags: c++, excel, qt, qaxobject

I need to create a new excel file from a Qt Application.
Is there any way to do date with QAxObject ?
I know that I can use QAxObject to read un excel file but I didn't find any example on the net that shows creating a new excel file using QAxObject.

Is this the right way to create such a file with Qt ?